# Add values to Dictionary<int,class> not all at once

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm trying to store data in a dictionary where the key is an ID and the values are of a class type. The class properties are not all added at the same time so I haven't used a constructor - unless there is a way to add new values using a constructor at a different times? The code below compiles, but I get a run time error saying the key has already been added.Thanks for the help.

```
public class Students
        {
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string SurName { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
            public double Score { get; set; }            
        }

        public void cmdTEST_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Dictionary<int, Students> Data = new Dictionary<int, Students>();
            Data.Add(5, new Students { FirstName = "Bob" });
            Data.Add(5, new Students { Age = 34 });             // run time error - "key already added"
            Data.Add(5, new Students { Score = 62 });

            // extract data
            double Score5 = Data[5].Score;
            double Age5 = Data[5].Age;
        }
```

Comment: Yes, you are adding multiple entries with 5 as its ID, obvious it throws an error

Comment: Use only one statement. **Data.Add(5, new Students { //provide all the fields here });**

Comment: You should improve the title of your question

Comment: I need to add properties at different points in the program, not all at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding same key multiple times which is not allowed. You can add all properties at once like below

```
Dictionary<int, Students> Data = new Dictionary<int, Students>();
Data.Add(5, new Students { FirstName = "Bob", Age = 34, Score = 62 });
```

And if you want to add values later you can use `key` to add values

```
Data.Add(5, new Students { FirstName = "Bob"});
Data[5].Age = 34;
Data[5].Score = 62;
```

Comment: Thanks, that really helps.